# Angular 1.6, $compileProvider and testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a project build with Angular **1.5**, with the **1.6** update the Angular team decided to disable pre-assigning controller bindings by default and if you want to enable them then you need to do: `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);`

This is not much of a problem with the application itself, all I need to do is add a config statement which uses `$compileProvider`

```
.config(function($compileProvider){ 
  $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
})
```

But when it comes to testing I've run into a snag. I have many *modules*, none of which use a `config`.

And I have tests which pull in all my modules and run something like this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myModule');
    inject(function ($injector) {
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    });
    // do stuff, run tests
});
```

These tests all fail now. The simple fix for this is to either add a config to ALL my modules and have compileProvider run on all those or to do something like this:

```
// myModule1.spec.js
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myModule', function ($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
    });
    ...
});

// myModule2.spec.js
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myModule2', function ($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
    });
    ...
});

// myModule3.spec.js
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myModule3', function ($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
    });
    ...
});
```

But the problem is I have just under a hundred components and would like to just set this in one place globally.

How could I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to configure this setting once for my whole app.

In karma.conf.js, after including angular-mocks.js, include another file that configures the ngMock module:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ngMock').config(function($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
    });
})();
```

This fixed all my tests.

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
beforeEach(module(function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
}));
...
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

or

```
angular.module('test.compile', []).config(function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
})
...
beforeEach(module('test.compile'));
...
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

There may be multiple `beforeEach(module(...))` blocks per spec. Since the modules that are loaded this way are stacked, the one with `$compileProvider` configuration belongs to top-level `describe` block.

Comment: Yes, just as I mentioned above, I have to do one of those two things, but I was hoping that I could do it globally somewhere. This is decent though... creating a module and copy pasting it's declaration

Comment: As it was said, you need to do this only once per top-level `describe` (likely one time per file). One of the purposes of `describe` blocks is to provide the optimal structure for `beforeEach`.

Comment: This is likely a problem that should be solved from the other end. It is good to have independent modules that can be tested separately. However, all stuff that is reused between them but doesn't hurt testability (route config will hurt, for example) should be contained in common modules. So it likely should be `angular.module('common', []).config(function ($compileProvider) { ... })`, and all of the modules that rely on this `$compile` behaviour or `common` services should load it.